# Python module importation error with pytest in a venv

Tags: python, docker, circleci

I have a package which contains several modules and a cython extension. I am able to install the package with the standard `pip install` command in virtual environments, it compiles my cython extension and so on. Everything works great. Now, I would like to test all of those with pytest. Here again, everything works great locally (or when I install the package on any other machine). However, when I use a docker image (the one from circleci) the compiled cython extension is not found when I run my tests with pytest.

The structure of my package is as follow

```
/home/circleci/dspt
├── dspt
│   ├── connection
│   ├── data
│   └── sp
│       ├── bilateral
│       │   ├── filters.pyx
│       └── signal_processing.py
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   └── test_data.py
```

I install this package in a virtual environment `/home/circleci/dspt/myvenv`. So, under this venv, I tried theses:

```
(myvenv) /home/circleci/$ python
>>>import dspt.sp.filters  # ok!
```

but if I change the directory

```
(myvenv) /home/circleci/dspt$ python
>>>import dspt.sp.filters  # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dspt.sp.filters'
```

I got the same error with pytest

```
(myvenv) /home/circle$ pytest dspt/tests/test_data.py
================================================= test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /home/circleci/dspt/tests, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: mock-1.10.1, metadata-1.8.0
collected 12 items / 1 errors / 11 selected                                                                            

======================================================== ERRORS ========================================================
________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_ecg_analysis.py _________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/circleci/dspt/tests/test_data.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/home/guillaume/src/dspt/tests/test_data.py:3: in <module>
    ???
dspt/dspt/sp/signal_processing.py:9: in <module>
    from dspt.sp.filters import bilateral_filter
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dspt.sp.filters'
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile the libs (cython principally) in Docker container, or did copied to container?

Comment: No, but the goal is to build a docker image so that I can run the tests on circleci. However, I verified that the Lib is well compiled in the folder `site-packages/dspt/sp` of the venv

Comment: Just for sanity check, write some test to import all the path lib. Import just `dspt`, then import `dspt.sp`. Just to check if there is no one *__init__.py* missing in some package.

Comment: It's already done. Furthermore, this peace of code is already in production and works very well. All the tests are run "manually" and there is not problem. The issue only occurs when I try to use the docker image :(

Comment: I dont fully understand, but after moving the venv in another directory, moving the tests code also in another directory and deleting the source code (the package is installed in the venv), then it works.

Comment: Good enough! Post the answer, other people could find it useful!